# What is the purpose of having both NSMutableString and NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Why does Objective C provide both class NSString and subclass NSMutableString rather than just provide NSMutableString?  Isn't a NSString equivalent to "const NSMutableString"?

In C++, you have only one string class, std::string, and if you want a constant you declare a const std:string.

I'm interested in knowing why I shouldn't just use NSMutableString everywhere and never bother with NSString?  There must be a reason, or the language designers wouldn't provide both.  maybe it takes up less storage or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for both classes is the same reason that you sometimes use a std::string and sometimes use a const std::string. However, unlike C++, Objective-C doesn't have const methods, so they instead separate const- from non-const- methods into two different classes. This is also seen in many of the core classes, such as NSArray (NSMutableArray), NSDictionary (NSMutableDictionary), etc.

Answer (score 6):

It is very possible, and even likely, that there are optimizations in place that are only allowed when strings are immutable.

In fact running

```
NSString *A = @"Bob";
NSString *B = @"Bob";
```

in the debugger immediately shows that they are both pointers to the same string.  In fact

```
NSString *C = [NSString stringWithString:@"Bob"];
NSString *D = [A copy];
```

both point to the same memory address as well.  Meanwhile

```
NSString *E = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Bob"];
```

points to a different string.

So yes, using NSStrings are more efficient in some cases.  And in general cocoa lends itself to returning a new copy of a string rather than an edited one.  However, I can't really argue that you shouldn't use a mutable string everywhere, but it does seem to go against the general guidelines for the framework.

In my own work I tend to only use mutable variants where I need to edit things directly.  It's just a little backwards from the C/C++ style of everything mutable unless you need a const, everything is const unless you need mutability.

Comment: What about `NSString *D = [E copy];` will it point to `E` or to another new string?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the general rule is "don't use a class whose purpose is to provide functionality you don't need".  If you need to change the contents of a string directly, use `NSMutableString`.  If not, use `NSString`.  In terms of size and how much heap space they take up, the classes themselves should be pretty similar.

Comment: I understand which class to use.  My question is why the language designers chose to split the functionality into two classes?

Comment: Because splitting the functionality allows the compiler and runtime to deliver higher performance in cases where the additional functionality is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the usage of an immutable string is a hint for the compiler which can perform optimizations by knowning it won't change.

Comment: As my tests show it also affects the way the runtime behaves.